# PHP in_array wildcard match

Tags: php

I am storing a list of prohibited words in an array:

```
$bad = array("test");
```

I am using the below code to check a username against it:

```
if (in_array ($username, $bad))
{
//deny
}
```

but I have a problem in that it only denies if the given username is exactly test, but I want it to also deny if the given username is Test, or TEST, or thisisatestok, or ThisIsATestOk.

Is it possible?

Comment: Use `strpos` for example or read about regular expressions and `preg_*` functions

Answer (score 4):

Although the other answers use regex and the `preg_*` family, you're probably better off using [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php), as it is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433492/preg-match-vs-strpos-for-match-finding) to use `preg_*` functions just for finding whether something is in a string - `stripos` is faster.

However, `stripos` does not take an array of needles, so I wrote a function to do this:

```
function stripos_array($haystack, $needles){
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
        if(($res = stripos($haystack, $needle)) !== false) {
            return $res;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function returns the offset if a match is found, or false otherwise.
Example cases:

```
$foo = 'evil string';
$bar = 'good words';
$baz = 'caseBADcase';
$badwords = array('bad','evil');
var_dump(stripos_array($foo,$badwords));
var_dump(stripos_array($bar,$badwords));
var_dump(stripos_array($baz,$badwords));
# int(0)
# bool(false)
# int(4)
```

Example use:

```
if(stripos_array($word, $evilwords) === false) {
    echo "$word is fine.";
}
else {
    echo "Bad word alert: $word";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By filtering each word in array with case insensitive regex , you can get the list of words contains needle.

```
<?php
$haystack = array('sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday');
$needle = 'DAY';
$matches = array_filter($haystack, function($var){return (bool)preg_match("/$needle/i",$var);});
print_r($matches);
```

outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => sunday
    [1] => monday
    [2] => tuesday
    [3] => wednesday
    [4] => thursday
    [5] => friday
    [6] => saturday
)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: While this might answer the question, it's custom to at least add some comments or explanation to your answer so people might actually learn something instead of copy / pasting code.

Comment: thanks for the advices , just elaborated the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$example = array('An example','Another example','One Example','Last example');
$searchword = 'last';
$matches = array();
foreach($example as $k=>$v) {
    if(preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $v)) {
        $matches[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Works with substrings and case insensitive.

Found here: [Search for PHP array element containing string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315536/search-for-php-array-element-containing-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can do with **strtolower()**

```
$words = array('i', 'am', 'very', 'bad');

$username = "VeRy";
$un = strtolower($username);

if (in_array($un, $words)){
    //found !
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to the question, but to the title (PHP in_array wildcard match):

```
function in_array_wildcards(string $needle, array $haystack, bool $case_insensitive = true):bool {
    foreach ($haystack as $value) {
        if (strpos($value, '*') !== false) {
            if ((bool)preg_match('/' . str_replace('*', '(.*)', $value) . '/' . (($case_insensitive) ? 'i' : ''), $needle)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            if ($case_insensitive) {
                if (strtolower($value) == strtolower($needle)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else {
                if ($value == $needle) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Works perfectly for

```
if (!in_array_wildcards($sFile, array('.htaccess', 'config.php', 'dbfs.php', 'error.php', 'front_content.php*', 'front_crcloginform.inc.php', 'index.php', 'robots.txt'))) {
```

(`'front_content.php*'` finds front_content.php, front_content.php.sic, front_content.php.s01, ...)