# PHP: Get value from string with preg_match, limited characters

Tags: php, regex

Sorry for the title, I don't know how to explain it better.

I must get **354607**  from the following string:

> ...jLHoiAAD1037**354607**Ij0Ij1Ij2...

The "354607" is dynamic, but it has the "1037" in any case before, and is in any case exactly 6 characters long.

The problem is, the string is about 50.000 up to 1.000.000 characters long. So I want a resource-friendly solution.

I tried it with:

```
preg_match_all("/1037(.*?){0,5}/", $new, $search1037);
```

and:

```
preg_match_all("/1037(.*?{0,5})/", $new, $search1037);
```

but, I don't know how to use regular expressions correctly.

I hope someone could help me!

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use, \d{6} represents 6 numbers

```
preg_match_all("/1037(\d{6})/", $new, $search1037);
```

returns an array with

```
array(
    0   =>  array(
        0   =>  1037354607
    ),
    1   =>  array(
        0   =>  354607
    )
)
```

Check this [demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/csz)

Comment: Thank you!! Saved me a lot of time and ugly workaround code!

Comment: Hy davcs86, can i ask you another question?

If i try to search for "06A906032HN" where the numbers (except 9060) and alphanumerics are variable, but everytime in the same format eg XX(X or Z)9060XXZZ (X stands for an INTENT and Z for alphanumeric (letter)) .. 

Did you know, how to deal with it ? 

It could be some like this in my string:
06A906032HN, 05B906032BC, 036906012AL

Comment: use `/(\d{2}[a-zA-Z\d]9060\d{2}[a-zA-Z\d]{2})/`, where `\d` is for digits and `[a-zA-Z\d]` is for alphanumeric (lower and uppercase), http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/cux

Comment: wow, super fast answer! Thank you! 
I only forget, better recognized one thing yet: The last 2 alphanumerics can be 1 or 2 characters long. Can this be integrated ?

Comment: lol, I was around here. In the last {2}, you can set a range like {1,2} to specify 1 to 2 characters, or {2,5} for 2 to 5 chars, so on.

Comment: I try around, but i dont get it to work :( And i found a few other exceptions. Would be very very fine from you if you can help me with this:

The string could be for exception: 8P0907115H, 06A906032HN, 03L906018A, 03G906012B, and so on..It looks like 90 is the only constante, and the last 1 or 2 alphanumerics

Comment: Okay, think i got it !! Thanks for your help, it learned me a little bit more about regex! I used this to solve: "\d{1}[a-zA-Z\d]{2}90\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}"
Big thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're concerned with finding a resource-friendly solution, you may be better off *not* using `preg_match`. Regular expressions tend to require more overhead in general, as discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433492/preg-match-vs-strpos-for-match-finding).

Instead, you could use `strstr()`:

```
$string = strstr($string,'1037');
```

Which will return the first instance of '1037' in `$string`, along with everything following it. Then, use `substr()`:

```
$string = substr($string,4,6);
```

Which returns the substring within `$string` starting at position 4 (where position 0 = `1`, position 1 = `0`, position 2 = `3`, position 3 = `7`, position 4 = beginning of 6 digits) and including 6 characters.

For fun, in one line:

```
$string = substr(strstr($string,'1037'),4,6);
```