# Search for text in a document and get the line as output

Tags: php

I am trying to make a `if` that will try to get a line of a document by searching after it. So it searches for "Registrar Handle" in the document and get the whole output of the line.

The problem I have is that is that I get this error: `Notice: Undefined index: Registrar Handle in C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxx\xx on line 29`

Would be nice if someone had a solution for this and maybe have an explanation for why it is happening?

```
$commandR = "whois ".mysql_result($domain, 0);  

$outputR = shell_exec($commandR);
$fhR = fopen('R.txt','w+');
fwrite($fhR,$outputR);
fclose($fhR);
  { 
    //.no
    if( strpos(file_get_contents("./R.txt"),$_GET['Registrar Handle'])){
       $fhR = fopen('A.txt','r');
       $R = fgets($_GET);
       fclose($fhA);
       Echo $R;
       //mysql_query("UPDATE `dom_oversikt`.`server1` SET `Registrar`='".$R."' WHERE `id` = '$id';");      
    }
```

Comment: And what problem do you have?

Comment: @u_mulder i updated it a little

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Why are you writing the output of a command to a file, only to read it again? You already had it in a variable. Also, I don't see any point in using the `$_GET` variable there.

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: Heard of regular expression ?

Comment: You should use a regular expression, can you post your file content !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the file you just created, get each line of the file until you reach the end of it and echo/return the line that contains the string you mentioned.

```
$searchedString = 'Registar Handle';
if (($handle = fopen("./R.txt", "r")) !== false) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $currentLineInFile = fgetss($handle, 4096);
        if(false !== strpos($currentLineInFile, $searchedString)){
            echo $currentLineInFile;
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

One could argue that you can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php) instead of strpos, but it's more complex and less fast (according to that [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433513/5820258) pointing to the php doc itself).

Regarding your error, it's only due to the fact that there is no key **'Registar Handle'** in the array **$_GET**.