# How to extract specific key string from array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, key, extract

This is my array

```
Array
        (
            [question_set] => Computer Basics
            [question] => Who are You ?
            [options_1] => RK
            [options_2] => KAMAL
            [options_3] => DPK
            [options_4] => NARENDRA
            [marks] => 5
            [negative_marks] => 1
            [type] => 1
        )
```

options_ are dynamic means it can be 4, 6 or 8.

I want to get value "**options**" from key of options_1 or so on. How can I do this.

Comment: Try to be more specific on your question, how many options? always 4? unlimited? what did you try? Also please tag PHP so it will be visible on relevant category.

Comment: Sorry @phobia82 one minute I update.

Comment: paste your expected output + what have you tried to accomplish it?

Comment: `foreach($array as $key => $value) {`, use `$key` and start with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strpos is way faster than preg_match, for reference: [strpos() vs preg_match()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433492/preg-match-vs-strpos-for-match-finding)

Using foreach and strpos() :

```
$arr = array(
        "question_set" => "Computer Basics",
        "question" => "Who are You ?",
        "options_1" => "RK",
        "options_2" => "KAMAL",
        "options_3" => "DPK",
        "options_4" => "NARENDRA",
        "marks" => 5,
        "negative_marks" => 1,
        "type" => 1
    );

$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
   if(strpos($key, "options") !== false) {
       $newArr[$key] = $value;
   }
}

echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($newArr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Welcome @Ramkishan! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array("options_1"   => "RK",  
               "options_213" => "21313",
               "options_4"   => "NARENDRA",
               "foo"         => "bar", 5 , 5 => 89009,
              );

$pattern = "/\boptions/";

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match($pattern,$key)){
        echo $key."\t=>\t".$value."\n";
    }
}
```